# How to unbind my own plugin from the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've created a jQuery plugin but I have not added a destroy method. It's bound to the document, and through a click event I want to unbind it.

The plugin is called like this:

```
$(document).myPlugin({
    option1: "1",
    option2: "2"
});
```

I thought to unbind it I would need to do:

```
$("#unbind").click(function(e) {
    $(document).unbind("myPlugin");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But after this event, the plugin is still functioning. What is the correct way to unbind this plugin? If it helps, to access the plugin's public methods I have to do something like this: `$(document).data('myPlugin').pubMethod();`

Comment: What does that mean for you, "unbind a plugin" ?

Comment: jQuery's `unbind` is meant to un-bind **events**, not plugins.

Comment: you need to unbind the events

Comment: OK, so the only way to programmatically stop the plugin from functioning is to create a destroy method in the plugin?

Comment: @tommyf, if your plugin is not trivial (i.e. if it creates elements and/or binds to events) then yes.

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice. I'll look at putting a destroy method into the plugin.